# PHP loop syntax issues

Tags: php

I need to add a counter to the loop as well as pulling contents. What is the syntax for adding the "and for ($ColCount = ColCount + 1)"

```
<?php $ColCount = 0?>
<!--get artwork thumbnails --> 
<?php
$dbname = 'pdartist2';
$table = 'artwork';
// query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT AID, ThumbFilePath, Title, DisplayOrder FROM artwork where SCID = '$SCID' ") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    foreach($row as $cell)
    and for ($ColCount = ColCount + 1) 

echo "$ColCount", "$cell";
}
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

Comment: Why not just use $ColCount++;

Comment: I think you actually mean row num, not col count, right?

Comment: @The old dog Seeing this questions and [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890026/more-php-syntax-trouble) [others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882203/php-syntax-trouble) I suggest you read more on PHP syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bruce said, you could just do $ColCount++, But also you could just count the results with mysql_num_rows

```php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT AID, ThumbFilePath, Title, DisplayOrder FROM artwork where SCID = '$SCID' ") or die(mysql_error());
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Shai

Comment: That will provide the number of **rows** in the result set, not a **column** count for each row.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea if that's valid in PHP. Maybe all it is is a forgotten `$` sign before `ColCount`. But you could just do it the normal way:

```
foreach($row as $cell) {
    $ColCount++;

    echo $ColCount . $cell;
}

$ColCount = 0;
```

Comment: nope your right, the code in the question is very odd. Not sure what is wanted but was going to post the same solution.

Comment: I posted the same solution, except with `$ColCount = 0;` in the right place, and got a downvote without comments :(

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
<!--get artwork thumbnails -->      
<?php  
$dbname = 'pdartist2';  
$table = 'artwork';  
// query  
$result = mysql_query("SELECT AID, ThumbFilePath, Title, DisplayOrder FROM artwork   where SCID = '$SCID' ") or die(mysql_error());  
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))  
{  
    $colCount = 0;  
    foreach($row as $cell) {  
      $colCount++;  
      echo "$ColCount", "$cell";  
    }  
}  
 mysql_free_result($result);  

?>
```

Comment: This place is awesome! How would I add if ColCount is 1 
    <div id="clear"></div>

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a semi-colon:

```
<?php $ColCount = 0?>
```

Should be:

```
<?php $ColCount = 0; ?>
```

And:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    foreach($row as $cell) {
        $ColCount++; // adds 1 to colcount

        echo $ColCount.$cell; // no need for quotes around variables. Also string concatination in PHP is using s dot (.)
    }
 }

mysql_free_result($result);
```

Comment: The column count has to be reset for each row. Doing it once on top of the script will just count the total number cells in the result set.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: as you can see I don't only use the total count, but I also print the colcount in the loop. That's what OP wants if I'm correct. I might be wrong though. Bit hard to tell what OP actually wants to achieve... :)

Comment: Yes, but you don't set it back to zero when you start printing a new row.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: I don't know if that is what the OP wants. He only states he needs a counter.

Answer (score 0):

What i'll do is use an array like that

```
    <!--get artwork thumbnails --> 
    <?php
    $dbname = 'pdartist2';
    $table = 'artwork';

    # Define array
    $Count = array();

    // query
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT AID, ThumbFilePath, Title, DisplayOrder FROM artwork where SCID = '.$SCID) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
        foreach($row as $cell){
            $Count[$Cell]['Count'] = $Count[$Cell]['Count']++;
        }

        echo $ColCount.', '.$cell;
    }
    mysql_free_result($result);
```

So you have the count for each colomn but what I suggest is to use the mysql_num_rows(); like that :

$Query = mysql_query...
$Count = mysql_num_rows($Query);

$Count will be a number ;)

Then if($Count > 0)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to count the number of columns in each row, then

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
   $colCount += count($row);
}
```

though I fail to see point of this. an SQL result set is a perfectly rectangular array. Variable number of rows, but every row will ALWAYS have the same number of fields as all the other rows in the result set. You'd only have to count the columns ONCE and cache that value.